# How to read excel sheet data in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How to read excel file in python I already used some program but not work.[image: I used that method given below in image]

[image: And the errors in that image]

I want to create folder folder of  separate sets [image: This is a excel sheet]

[image: I want to create sets folder inside 3D folder given below in image]

Comment: The question contains no code or errors, so it's impossible to help. Images aren't code, they can't be copied, tested or googled. There are a *lot* of tutorials that show how to read or write Excel files using Pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Comment: BTW if the error tells you you have an invalid path, you need to fix that path. It means you used a path that either contains invalid characters or makes no sense

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code and error samples as text formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it helps you in understanding how to read excel file, try to correctly specify your file path. In my case ./ means current file where my python file exist. Move your excel file where your python file exist

**Install:**

```
pip install pandas openpyxl
```

**Solution 1**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('./TfidfVectorizer_sklearn.xlsx')
df
```

**Solution 2**

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('./TfidfVectorizer_sklearn.xlsx')

sheet = book.active
cells = sheet['A1': 'D5']

for c1, c2, c3, c4 in cells:
    print(f"{c1.value} {c2.value} {c3.value} {c4.value}")
```

Comment: He is using windows OS but he have to correctly specify the path ./ means current relative path.